# How can I choose a select option in jQuery as though it were clicked with the mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am building a search tool with various select drop downs that populate with options via AJAX. The possible options populated are based on the the option chosen in the preceding select drop down. For the purpose of this tool, I want to have the first select box hidden but still need to select an option in that box so that it triggers the AJAX call on the following box, something that is supposed to happen as the result of an "onchange" event.

I've tried all kinds of different code to simulate a mouse click selection of a particular option but, while I can get the option selected, it still isn't triggering the event properly to set off the AJAX call in the following select. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
jQuery('#form select').first().val('the-value').trigger('click').trigger('change');
```

From everything I've read, that should set the option value and trigger a change event much like clicking the option. Still, this isn't working. Thanks!

Comment: Is your `change` function above this call?

Comment: @CarlMarkham This was the issue I think as the change function was being called separately within a plugin that must be running after the script file I'm editing.. I've been struggling with this all day - thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to use val(), like any other field...

```
$("select").val("2").change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Loenix34/3LbjY/

We also use change() to call associated events.

Comment: I think this is close but still, this isn't allowing me to cause an effect to the subsequent select as though I had clicked it. Here is a really basic example of what I am trying to do ([link]http://jsfiddle.net/maniacaldesign/57Wf7/). I want the initial select to be set and as a condition of the selected value changing on the first, for the 2nd value switching to 5 to also be triggered. Does that make sense? @Loenix

Comment: Oh, I see - per Cark Markham's note above - I didn't have my change function call above (as it is actually called in a separate plugin file called via php. I get it now - thanks for the help!@Leonix

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the value of the select, set the selected property of the given option, and then trigger a change.

```
$("option[value='the-value']").prop('selected', true);
$("#form select:first").change();
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vXTfD/)